# solace-jms-spring-boot vs solace-spring-cloud

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace

I am using solace-jms-spring-boot and planning to migrate to solace-spring-cloud. Are there any limitation that need to be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to answer your question since you have not stated what are your use case and `solace-spring-cloud` is just an umbrella for multiple projects. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)